# Additional Language in KDE

Tags: keyboard, kde, language-support, layout

I just installed KDE desktop environment and I want to install an additional language (Urdu) in unity 2d I was using it butt in KDE Its seems very difficult. Some where I get to know about to change some thing in etc/x11/xkb/symbols but when I tried there was no such directory. Pleas help me out to wright Urdu in KDE.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want additional keyboard go to

*System Settings → Input Devices → Keyboard Layouts*

and add languages that you need

[image]

You can also display language indicator in statusbar.

Answer (score 1):

*System Settings* → *Locale* → *System Languages*

Select *Urdu*, mark the available components and click *Apply*.